# Does RIA Services requires an extra install on the server?

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

If I want to deploy an ASP.NET application that hosts RIA Services endpoints for a Silverlight application, do I have to *install* anything extra on the web server?  Or is it just some extra DLLs that can be deployed to my applications Bin folder?

I know that when you are doing RIA Services development there are additional toolkits and what-not to install, but I'm not sure if those are needed on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your webserver will need to have .Net 4 installed, and you will need some DLLs.  It is possible to publish by setting these DLLs to "Copy Local" = true.

- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework
- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting
- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server

You can also just install the exe as shown here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151218095500/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/deepm/archive/2010/03/15/are-you-a-hoster-and-want-to-support-ria-services.aspx)

Further Reading: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saurabh/deploying-application-built-using-ria-services-rc)